# Check for duplicate field values in Dynamic Table rows

Tags: jquery, warnings, jquery-ui-autocomplete, duplicates

On my quest to develop an easy to use, not so easy to programme user interface, I have come accross an issue of duplicate entries.

I would like to detect if a duplicate entry has been made and if so warn the user of said duplicates.

I have tried quite a few methods, but they only really seem to work on static tables, I on the other hand, need to be able to detect duplicates in a Dynamic Table.

Here is the one call I have used, to no avail:

```
  var fData = $('[name^="product_name"]').val();
var val = $(this).val();
for (var o in fData) { 
if (fData[o]===val) {
    alert("duplicate value");
    break;
  }    
}
```

What I am trying to check is the variable of "product_name" against itself when it has been selected from the autocomplete list.

Would it perhaps be better to use another field?

Any suggestions, snippets are indeed welcome.

thank you

Comment: DO NOT pass you login credentials on community sites..all fingers are not same